# Holt winters Alpha

Tags: holtwinters

I am trying to get the HoltWinters Alpha function added.
I have a Table called Sales1 and the code should refer to this table.
Is there anyone who can correct  or amend  my code below ,so i get the Holtwinters Alpha instead of the Chronbachs Alpha?

## Holt winters calc (need this probably amended)

```
library(forecast)
library(Metrics
```

)

```
read_file(sales1)
x <- sales

x = c(Sales1)  
mSES = HoltWinters(x, alpha = 0.5, beta = FALSE, gamma = FALSE)  
mHW = HoltWinters(x, alpha = 0.5, beta = FALSE, gamma = FALSE)
mSES$SSE  
mHW$SSE

HoltWinters(x, alpha = NULL, beta = NULL, gamma = NULL,
            seasonal = c("additive", "multiplicative"),
            start.periods = 2, l.start = NULL, b.start = NULL,
            s.start = NULL,
            optim.start = c(alpha = 0.3, beta = 0.1, gamma = 0.1),
            optim.control = list())
```

## chronbachs alpha calc

```
read_file(sales1)
library(tidyverse)
library(psy)
```

## Number of rows before to take into account

```
rolling = 2

sales1 <- sales::sales(  ~date, ~sales,)
#Lag
sales1 = sales1 %>%  mutate(lagsales = lag(sales))

#Rolling Chronbachs Alpha.:( I need the Holtwinter Alpha here )

sales1$alpha = c(  rep(NA, rolling), 
  map_dbl((rolling + 1):nrow(sales1), function(x){
    cronbach(sales1 %>% select(sales, lagsales) %>% slice((x-rolling):x))$alpha
  })
)
sales1
```

tibbet from Sales1 table:

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~seq, ~date, ~sales,
  1, "3/01/2017", 40,
  2, "4/01/2017", 2,
  3, "5/01/2017", 2,
  4, "6/01/2017", 2,
  5, "7/01/2017", 30,
  6, "8/01/2017", 2,
  7, "1/02/2017", 9,
  8, "2/02/2017", 5,
  9, "3/02/2017", 65,
  10, "4/02/2017", 3,
  11, "5/02/2017", 65